# Can i adjust estimote stickers broadcasting range?

Tags: beacon, estimote, eddystone-url

I need to use estimote stickers for one of my requirement, can i change its broadcasting range with eddystone-url protocol as proximity/location beacons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have emailed about the above question to the estimote team.

They are saying that, **We can adjust the broadcasting power of stickers with eddystone-url as protocol**. But they won't recommend it because it decreases responsiveness with an already limited range of stickers.